# How can jQuery's Datepicker get away with using a single unique id when multiple instances are created?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uniqueidentifier

I've been doing some research on jQuery's Datepicker plugin. I was curious as to how he created his nodes and modified them.

What I found was interesting:

```
@ 113:   this.dpDiv = bindHover($('<div id="' + this._mainDivId + '" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>'));
```

The bindHover function is not really important to consider, it takes the reference and delegates a few events such as mouseover etc.

What is interesting is the id attribute, it says this._mainDivId so I checked it out and...

```
@ 34:       this._mainDivId = 'ui-datepicker-div'; // The ID of the main datepicker division
```

There is not use of a unique id, it is a set id. I figured it would have to be unique because often times there are more than one datepickers used on a page.

This is jQuery, it MUST be good practice... I just can't figure out why or how this is helpful.

Comment: How many date pickers are shown at the same time?

Comment: I think it's because you can only have one Datepicker element on the same page, if you try to open it on a another field, the datepicker element is still the same but it will just _move_ to the correct position.

Comment: "*This is jQuery, it MUST be good practice*" jQuery and jQuery UI are not perfect. nothing is perfect. ;)

Comment: all that time spend sifting source code...a quick look in browser console at live html would have given you the answer  **no duplication**

Comment: Have you checked the rendered HTML or the [**jQuery UI documentation/example on the datepicker**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)? Have you seen multiple datepickers with the same id in your rendered HTML or are you simply assuming it must be?

Comment: @Francois I've seen the examples, and even I have implemented it on my webpages. I am asking only out of desire to become a better programmer... I don't know why I'm getting downvoted so much on this question. In one webpage I've made, I have both an inline datepicker and a datepicker attached to some other inputs. I assumed that each were a separate element and after looking at the code, I was confused as to why separate elements would share the same id.

Comment: @Alexander Well I have a webpage where I have multiple datepickers on a few different elements, including an inline datepicker. However, the inline datepicker is always in a div that is hidden while I'm accessing the other inputs that contain datepicker attachments. But, only 1 datepicker has ever been shown at a time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glancing at the source, it looks like though there may be many datepicker instances on a page, only one datepicker window is open at a time ([see example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)). Every datepicker uses the same `dpDiv` element to show its content, so that div is given a single unique ID.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thank you for a good answer. I'm glad to get an answer to this, even if the vote is it's a bad question. I didn't consider that it was only one element just being moved around.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the html generated from adding a datepicker to two inputs.  See the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/AC5Py/

```
<body>
<input id="picker1" class="hasDatepicker">
<input id="picker2" class="hasDatepicker">
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; top: 21px; left: 168.7px; z-index: 1; display: block;">
</body>
```

It seems like only one date picker component is added to the page and it is reused by every input specified as a date picker established on the page.  Basically, they are reusing the markup generated for the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

when you add datepicker to an input through jquery it is done like this

```
$('#startDate').datePicker({..});
```

the unique id is `startDate`  jquery will handle changing of id's and classes while it is rendering that specific datepicker.  Only one date picker can be displayed at a time, I wouldn't worry about different elements having the same id's , as long as you don't give them the same id's on your own - all will be well